# Series expansion for $\arctan(1-x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Series expansion for $\arctan(1-x)$

I try to expand this function into its Taylor series by means of differentiating it and then integrating it terms by terms but I fail to obtain the correct result.

The derivative of $\arctan(1-x)=-\dfrac{1}{x^2-2x+2}$. By using long division, I can obtain the series expansion for $-\dfrac{1}{x^2-2x+2}$ and it is

$-\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{x^2}{4}+\dfrac{x^4}{8}+\dfrac{x^5}{8}+\dfrac{x^6}{16}...$

I integrate this series terms by terms and I obtain:
$0-\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{x^2}{4}-\dfrac{x^3}{12}+\dfrac{x^5}{40}+\dfrac{x^6}{48}-\dfrac{x^7}{122}...$

The series according to Wolfram is: $\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{x^2}{4}-\dfrac{x^3}{12}+\dfrac{x^5}{40}+\dfrac{x^6}{48}-\dfrac{x^7}{122}...$.

I notice that if I use the indefinite integral, there is going to be an arbitrary constant left after the integrating process. How do I obtain this $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$? Without it, is my series wrong?

Is there any other methods to expand this function into Maclaurin series without directly employing the Maclaurin formula

Comment: You "integrate this series" ... but of course when you do an indefinite integral, you always have a "$+C$" on the end.  Of course that $\pi/4$ is $\arctan(1)$, the value of your function at $x=0$.

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1858869/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3469364/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1069869/96384.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the derivative of $\arctan z$ is
\begin{equation*}
(\arctan z)^{(n)}
=\frac{(n-1)!}{(2z)^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{k}{n-k-1}\frac{(2z)^{2k}}{(1+z^2)^{k+1}}.
\end{equation*}
The function $\frac{\arctan z}{z}$ has Taylor's series expansion
\begin{equation}\label{arctan-pi-4-ser-eq}
\frac{\arctan z}{z}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\Bigl[\frac{\pi}{4}+T(n)\Bigr](z-1)^n,\quad |z-1|<\sqrt{2}\,,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}\label{T(n)-dfn-notation}
T(n)=
\begin{cases}
0, & n=0;\\ \displaystyle
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2^{k/2}k}\sin\frac{3k\pi}{4}, & n\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Hence, we derive
\begin{equation}\label{arctan(1-z)-pi-4-ser-eq}
\frac{\arctan (1-z)}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Bigl[\frac{\pi}{4}+T(n)\Bigr]z^n,\quad |z|<\sqrt{2}\,,
\end{equation}
which can be rearranged as
\begin{align}
\arctan (1-z)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Bigl[\frac{\pi}{4}+T(n)\Bigr]z^n
-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Bigl[\frac{\pi}{4}+T(n)\Bigr]z^{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Bigl[\frac{\pi}{4}+T(n)\Bigr]z^n
-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Bigl[\frac{\pi}{4}+T(n-1)\Bigr]z^{n}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[T(n)-T(n-1)]z^n\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{n/2}n}\sin\frac{3n\pi}{4}z^n\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^2}{4}-\frac{z^3}{12}+\frac{z^5}{40}+\frac{z^6}{48}+\frac{z^7}{112}-\frac{z^9}{288}-\dotsm.
\end{align}

1. Feng Qi and Mark Daniel Ward, *Closed-form formulas and properties of coefficients in Maclaurin's series expansion of Wilf's function*, arXiv (2021), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08576v1.

Answer (score 1):

When you integrate it, you get a $+C$. To get it's value, you can substitute in $x=0$ to get that $C=\arctan(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n\ge1$, we have
\begin{align*}
[\arctan(1-x)]^{(n)}
&=-\biggl(\frac{1}{x^2-2x+2}\biggr)^{(n-1)}\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^kk!}{(x^2-2x+2)^{k+1}} B_{n-1,k}(2x-2,2,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&\to-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^kk!}{2^{k+1}} B_{n-1,k}(-2,2,0,\dotsc,0), \quad x\to0\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^kk!}{2^{k+1}} 2^k B_{n-1,k}(-1,1,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^kk!}{2^{k+1}} 2^k \frac{1}{2^{n-k-1}}\frac{(n-1)!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k-1}(-1)^{2k-n+1}\\
&=(-1)^{n}\frac{(n-1)!}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k2^{k} \binom{k}{n-k-1}
\end{align*}
where we used the formula
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-x-1-0-eq}
B_{n,k}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)
=\frac{1}{2^{n-k}}\frac{n!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k}x^{2k-n}.
\end{equation}
Consequently, we arrive at
\begin{equation*}
\arctan(1-x)=\frac\pi4+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^n}\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k2^{k} \binom{k}{n-k-1}\Biggr]\frac{x^n}{n}.
\end{equation*}

References

1. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Article 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
2. F. Qi, D.-W. Niu, D. Lim, and Y.-H. Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. **491** (2020), no. 2, Article 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
3. Feng Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of two functions containing squares of inverse cosine function, closed-form formula for specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for real powers of Pi*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 710--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0157.